# Perl : Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at new.pl line 24

Tags: json, perl, hash

```
1. my $source_json = $_;
2. my $data = parse_json_safe($source_json);
3. my %data=%{$data};   #Error .
```

Error:

```
**Error** : Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at new.pl , <FH> line 3.
```

This is just a part of the code. Someone please explain why it is giving this warning or error. I am new to Perl.
It has been solved guys, can you take your down votes back. I  cant ask another questions. Please! guys.

Comment: Could you please write `$source_json` and use `Data::Dumper;` to print `$data`, So we can have a look.

Comment: Writing "***URGENT!!!***" really doesn't achieve anything when you're not paying people for their work :-)

Comment: @TheGr8Adakron: your urgent begging has been edited out of three out of your prior four questions, and now this one as well. What do we need to do to make it clear **these phrases do not belong here?**

Comment: (Note that if you get too many downvotes your account will automatically reach a question ban, so paying attention to this feedback is a good idea).

Answer (score 3):

`parse_json_safe` returns `undef` ([and displays warning](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON-Parse/lib/JSON/Parse.pod#parse_json_safe)), and you need hash reference in order to deference a hash.

You should be using [`parse_json()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON-Parse/lib/JSON/Parse.pod#parse_json) which would throw exception since you're not doing any checking.